# Error: Problem in switching bw Multiple Tabs. Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

So I am trying to create a profile screen with 3 tabs... profile, recent and review however upon trying to do so I am facing an error. I am not able to represent all 3 tabs. Recent tab has this widget

```
  Widget RecentItems() {
   return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance
              .collection("users")
              .document(uid)
              .collection("recent")
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            List orders = List.from(Map.from(snapshot.data.data)['orders']);
            Map order;
            for (int i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
              if (orders[i]['orderId'] == widget.map['orderId'] &&
                  orders[i]['homemaker'] == widget.map['homemaker']) {
                order = orders[i];
                break;
              }
            }
            if (snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
              return Center(
                  child:
                  Text("OOPS, Looks like no one is serving!"));
            }
            print(order);
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data.documents[0].data);
              return Container(
                height: 400,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        width: MediaQuery
                            .of(context)
                            .size
                            .width,
                        height: 85,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Expanded(child: Text(
                                    "${snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                        .data["dishname"]}", style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)),
                                  //Icon: how to access if food is veg or not
                                ],
                              ),
                              // SizedBox(height:5),
                              Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Expanded(child: Text(
                                    "${snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                        .data["homemaker"]}",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),)),
                                  Text("${snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                      .data["rating"]}",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.star, color: Colors.yellow.shade800,
                                    size: 20,)
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5),
                              //How to access order date
                              Text(
                                "Ordered ${DateTime
                                    .parse(order['order_placed_at']
                                    .toDate()
                                    .toString())
                                    .day}/${DateTime
                                    .parse(order['order_placed_at']
                                    .toDate()
                                    .toString())
                                    .month}/${DateTime
                                    .parse(order['order_placed_at']
                                    .toDate()
                                    .toString())
                                    .year}}",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              );
            } //
          }),
    );
  }
```

This is how I am trying to display them...

```
int _selectedIndex = 3;

  var uid;

  Future<String> getUser() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser().then((val) {
      setState(() {
        uid = val.uid;
      });
    });
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
    if (_selectedIndex == 0) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/ExplorePage");
    } else if (_selectedIndex == 1) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/SearchPage");
    } else if (_selectedIndex == 2) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/FavoriteScreenPage",
          arguments: uid);
    }
  }
  TabController tabController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 20),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 54,
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
              showSelectedLabels: false,
              showUnselectedLabels: false,
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.8),
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
              selectedItemColor: Color(0xffFE506D),
              onTap: _onItemTapped,
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.explore,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  title: Text("Explore"),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black),
                  title: Text("Search"),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border, color: Colors.black),
                  title: Text("Faavorites"),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity, color: Color(0xffFE506D)),
                  title: Text("Shop"),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )),
      drawer: DrawerWidget(uid: this.uid),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(25),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25)),
              child: Container(
                height: 230,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  // border: new Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      offset: Offset(20.0, 30.0),
                      blurRadius: 40.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        width: 155,
                        height: 155,
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            image: new DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                image: new NetworkImage("$_image")))),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Text("$_name",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
              child: Container(
                // margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                child: Container(
                // margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          menuType = "profile";
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          child: Text(
                            getTranslated(context, "profile"),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: menuType == "profile" ? 20.0 : 17.0,
                                color: menuType == "profile"
                                    ? Colors.black
                                    : Colors.black45,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontFamily: "Gilroy"),
                          )),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          menuType = "reviews";
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          child: Text(
                            getTranslated(context, "reviews"),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: menuType == "reviews" ? 20.0 : 17.0,
                                color: menuType == "reviews"
                                    ? Colors.black
                                    : Colors.black45,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontFamily: "Gilroy"),
                          )),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          menuType = "recent";
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          child: Text(
                            getTranslated(context, "recent"),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: menuType == "recent" ? 20.0 : 17.0,
                                color: menuType == "recent"
                                    ? Colors.black
                                    : Colors.black45,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontFamily: "Gilroy"),
                          )),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              ),
            ),
            menuType== "profile"? this.ProfileItems() : this.ReviewItems() : this.RecentItems(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this how I have declared menu type

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
  var _name, _uid, _phone, _language, _location, _image, menuType = "profile";
  Language language;
```

I am not able to display the 3 tabs. The moment I remove recent widget it starts displaying.
Error displayed:

```
The following assertion was thrown building UserProfilePage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#47da7]], state: _UserProfilePageState#87b63):
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 285 pos 10: 'data != null'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  UserProfilePage file:///C:/Flutter/Naniz_eats/lib/main.dart:166:59
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new Text (package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart:285:10)
#3      _UserProfilePageState.build (package:econoomaccess/UserProfilePage.dart:708:34)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4334:27)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4223:15)
#6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
...
```

Comment: which of the code posted is `UserProfilePage.dart`

Comment: all of these snippets are part of userprofilepage.dart

Comment: this is the link to whole code at once: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qs4ajPJ0DBjserBJ3iBZmPXPz1zTP7tIYSh8vceVQn8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you point me to line 708?

Comment: it goes like this probably at the end of code
child: Text(
                            getTranslated(context, "recent"),
                            style: TextStyle(

Comment: where is the getTranslated() from? can you post the code for that?

Comment: String getTranslated(BuildContext context, String key) {
  return AppLocalizations.of(context).translate(key);
}

Comment: i posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems the text is not present in your AppLocalization so you should do null check like this

```
String getTranslated(BuildContext context, String key) { 
   return AppLocalizations.of(context).translate(key) ?? "**text not found"; 
}
```